# how to change the color of iPhone status bar?

Tags: ios, colors

**How to change the  color  of iPhone  status bar during the IOS developing With Xcode?**

Comment: Google > ios 7 status bar color

Comment: @MarcMosby not sure about that, the ios 7 status bar color is pretty great..

Answer (score 0):

in info.plist of the project add `View controller-based status bar appearance` and then set its value to `YES`. after that place the following method in any of the views you want to change the status bar color.

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

that should do the trick. just two simple steps. good luck.